# Can't create a script for creating databases with diff names. PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

guys. I would like to make this script, or other with the same effect:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

To create databases with different names, for example:
First time will create database named "news1", the next time, the script will just do sth. like that: news1+1 = news2, and will create database called news2, and so on...

I hope you got my point and I'll really appreciate it if you help me to make this...
Regards, Denis Saidov.

Comment: Why would you need separate databases for that?! Just make the number a field in each table. -- And what's your specific coding question anyway? How to increment a numeric suffix, and concatenate to a string?

Comment: Creating separate databases would definitely be overkill...

Comment: Well, I wanna make a news system. And I think that somehow I'll be able to make it like this.

Comment: If you not need that the numeric suffix is an incremented value you can concat a timestamp value...

Comment: @DenisSaidov this is a bad way to do. What kind of data are you trying to store?

Comment: Maybe if you tell what should be the PHP script of emptying a single row or collumn in the table, I'll be very happy and I think that I won't need to use the procedure in my first post. :)

Comment: 3 collumns: "ImgCode", "NewsInfo", "NewsTitle";

Comment: To "empty a single row" you'd just execute a SQL `DELETE` query...I'm not sure how that would help solve your problem though. Of course, a better description of your problem would help.

Comment: @DenisSaidov - Learn about normalization in a database and what that means. Also why try a bit/complex project when learning the basics and doing minor projects first?

Answer (score 0):

To do this I'm guessing that you don't just want to loop 100 times?

You will need to save a variable to a text file then call it again.

Writing $text to a file:

```
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('filename.php', $var);
```

Retrieving it again:

```
include 'filename.php';
echo $text;
```

All together:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$db_number = get_var();
$my_db = 'news' . $db_number;
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$my_db,$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }
$new_db_number = $db_number + 1;
save_var($new_db_number);
mysql_close($con);

function save_var($var) {
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('filename.php', $var);
}
function get_var()
include 'filename.php';
return $text;
}
?>
```

PS I think that should work only typing not tested

Answer (score 0):

The database should be static. It is a one off event to create the database along with:

- Tables
- Indexes
- Various constraints
- Triggers
- Stored procedures

This can be done with a SQL script.

Then the PHP stuff accessing this database only needs to use `select`, `insert`, `delete` or `update` statements - or as I prefer using stored procedures.

You are going to have a lot of headaches having multiple databases. Also I would hate to  have to write a PHP script to do that each time and to administrate them.